# Show hide div using v-if causes button to not trigger

Tags: vue.js

I have a timer within a div, that I'm showing/hiding using v-if.  The start/stop button works when there is no v-if, however when I add the v-if the button no longer works.  The console is showing me nothing to debug with.

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried here? And link to a reproduction?

Comment: When v-if="false", the component is not created or mounted.